# How do I put a bracket around a subset of equations in a cases environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, cases

So I have a set of aligned equations already in cases. However, I would like to put a subset of these equation in another set of cases (pointing towards the right) and label them using the text "Key"

[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `You might try  nesting an `rcases` environment (from `mathtools`) in `cases`.

Comment: what you try so far?